# java.nio.ByteBuffer wrap method partly working with sbt run

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have an issue where I read a bytestream from a big file ~ (100MB) and after some integers I get the value 0 (but only with sbt run ). When I hit the play button on IntelliJ I get the value I expected > 0.

My guess was that the environment is somehow different. But I could not spot the difference.

```scala
// DemoApp.scala
import java.nio.{ByteBuffer, ByteOrder}

object DemoApp extends App {
  val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/HandRanks.dat")
  val handRanks = new Array[Byte](inputStream.available)
  inputStream.read(handRanks)
  inputStream.close()

  def evalCard(value: Int) = {
    val offset = value * 4
    println("value: " + value)
    println("offset: " + offset)
    ByteBuffer.wrap(handRanks, offset, handRanks.length - offset).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt
  }

  val cards: List[Int] = List(51, 45, 14, 2, 12, 28, 46)

  def eval(cards: List[Int]): Unit = {
    var p = 53
    cards.foreach(card =>  {
      println("p = " + evalCard(p))
      p = evalCard(p + card)
    })
    println("result p: " + p);
  }
  eval(cards)
}
```

The HandRanks.dat can be found here: (I put it inside a directory called resources)
https://github.com/Robert-Nickel/scala-texas-holdem/blob/master/src/main/resources/HandRanks.dat

build.sbt is:

```
name := "LoadInts"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
```

On my windows machine I use sbt 1.4.6 with Oracle Java 11

You will see that the `evalCard` call will work 4 times but after the fifth time the return value is 0. It should be higher than 0, which it is when using IntelliJ's play button.

Comment: I guess it is because IntelliJ overrides java defaults, which increase the memory data. But what is that the problem you are trying to solve? Probably there is a better way to do it that using `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading a whole content. This

```
val handRanks = new Array[Byte](inputStream.available)
```

allocates only as much as `InputStream` buffer and then you read the amount in buffer with

```
inputStream.read(handRanks)
```

Depending of defaults you will process different amount but they will never be 100MB of data. For that you would have to read data into some structure in the loop (bad idea) or process it in chunks (with iterators, stream, etc).

```
import scala.util.Using

// Using will close the resource whether error happens or not
Using(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/HandRanks.dat")) { inputStream =>
  def readChunk(): Option[Array[Byte]] = {
    // can be done better, but that's not the point here
    val buffer = new Array[Byte](inputStream.available)
    val bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
    if (bytesRead >= 0) Some(buffer.take(bytesRead))
    else None
  }
  
  @tailrec def process(): Unit = {
    readChunk() match {
      case Some(chunk) =>
        // do something
        process()
      case None =>
        // nothing to do - EOF reached
    }
  }

  process()
}
```